# Accessing Uploaded Files in Golang

Tags: http, file-upload, go

I'm having issues with accessing files i upload w/ golang. I'm really new to the language and have gone through more than a few attempts-- can't find any answers to this online either.

What am i doing wrong? In this code, i never get to the block where it lists the  # of files uploaded.

```
func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  fmt.Println("handling req...")

  if r.Method =="GET"{
    fmt.Println("GET req...")

  } else {

    //parse the multipart stuff if there
    err := r.ParseMultipartForm(15485760)

    //
    if err == nil{
        form:=r.MultipartForm
        if form==nil {
            fmt.Println("no files...")

        } else {
            defer form.RemoveAll()
            // i never see this actually occur
            fmt.Printf("%d files",len(form.File))
        }
    } else {
        http.Error(w,err.Error(),http.StatusInternalServerError)
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }
  }

  //fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hi there, I love %s!", r.URL.Path[1:])
  fmt.Println("leaving...")
}
```

#### Update

I was able to get the above code to work. Which is great. The answer below shows how to do it async, which may be a better code sample than mine.

Comment: What _do_ you see? If it never enters the block with len(form.File) which other execution path does it take?

Comment: @Volker i see it continually saying that there are no files-- the `form==nil` path

Comment: Dummy code (just your handler on "/" and main func) shows that your code correctly recognize files (posted with `curl -F file=@somefile http://localhost:8080`). If you trying to upload files from page, do you set correct content type in form?

Comment: Also, if you want to easy handle of small files, you may look at Request.FormFile method, which would parse form for you. Otherwise, if you want to handle file uploads in streaming fashion (FormFile will buffer entire file in memory/tmpfiles), you have to use Request.MultipartReader

Comment: @mechmind do you have a link to an example perchance? i'd really appreciate seeing the streaming version

Comment: @Micah http://play.golang.org/p/dVhyEDbzOy Note, if you are using streaming reader, you cannot rely on field order.

Comment: Here's example code for uploading files using golang. It uses `Request.FormFile()` instead of `Request.MultipartForm` https://github.com/Unknwon/build-web-application-with-golang_EN/tree/master/code/src/apps/ch.4.4

Comment: I think this is case closed, although it would be great to see answers.. @mechmind, could you please post as answer - I'm sure the OP will accept

Comment: @Jonno im primed for acceptance

Comment: @micah Where is the async answer? I'm interested in that. I'm afraid that if I process files in the background (goroutine) after returning the repsonse to user, go might release file resources.

Answer (score 13):

**Answer** *Download the latest golang release.*

I experienced the problem before, using the old golang versions, I do not know what happened, but with the latest golang its working. =)

My upload handler code below...
Full code at: http://noypi-linux.blogspot.com/2014/07/golang-web-server-basic-operatons-using.html

```
  // parse request  
  const _24K = (1 << 10) * 24  
  if err = req.ParseMultipartForm(_24K); nil != err {  
       status = http.StatusInternalServerError  
       return  
  }  
  for _, fheaders := range req.MultipartForm.File {  
       for _, hdr := range fheaders {  
            // open uploaded  
            var infile multipart.File  
            if infile, err = hdr.Open(); nil != err {  
                 status = http.StatusInternalServerError  
                 return  
            }  
            // open destination  
            var outfile *os.File  
            if outfile, err = os.Create("./uploaded/" + hdr.Filename); nil != err {  
                 status = http.StatusInternalServerError  
                 return  
            }  
            // 32K buffer copy  
            var written int64  
            if written, err = io.Copy(outfile, infile); nil != err {  
                 status = http.StatusInternalServerError  
                 return  
            }  
            res.Write([]byte("uploaded file:" + hdr.Filename + ";length:" + strconv.Itoa(int(written))))  
       }  
  }
```

Comment: const _24K = (1 << 20) * 24

<-- that's 24**MB** isn't it? 2^20 = 1MB

Comment: Should I delete files in temporary directory after copy? I've noticed files, which size is greater than _24K (or whatever), appear in my '/tmp' dir and I really have no idea how I can delete them os.Remove(hdr.Filename) does nothing, just can not find temporary file (since its name is not the same as uploaded file has).

Answer (score 5):

If you know they key of the file upload you can make it a bit simpler I think (this is not tested):

```
infile, header, err := r.FormFile("file")
if err != nil {
    http.Error(w, "Error parsing uploaded file: "+err.Error(), http.StatusBadRequest)
    return
}

// THIS IS VERY INSECURE! DO NOT DO THIS!
outfile, err := os.Create("./uploaded/" + header.Filename)
if err != nil {
    http.Error(w, "Error saving file: "+err.Error(), http.StatusBadRequest)
    return
}

_, err = io.Copy(outfile, infile)
if err != nil {
    http.Error(w, "Error saving file: "+err.Error(), http.StatusBadRequest)
    return
}

fmt.Fprintln(w, "Ok")
```

Comment: What exactly is insecure about the way you create the file?  What's the preferred method?

Comment: The filename might be `../../../../../etc/passwd` or whatever. Basically I didn't sanitise the filename or check that no other file existed there already. It may be the case the go removes \ and / from filenames but I wouldn't rely on it.

Comment: That's what I thought.  Thanks! I suppose the best thing to do would be to not allow / or \
Am I correct in thinking that or is there more to worry about?

Comment: That should do it (at least on non-windows platforms). I would whitelist characters I know are safe and uri-encode the rest.